# The blade template engine can be used with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-blade

The template engine called blade can be used with codeigniter or pure php? I know that it can be used with laravel and I'd like to know if also can be used with any other php framework or with pure php

Comment: First you need to understand how `composer` works and learn to use it. http://getcomposer.org

Comment: ok, but then blade can be used with codeigniter or not?

Comment: Yes, you can with codeigniter. https://github.com/laperla/codeigniter-Blade

Answer (score 2):

`Blade` can be used stand-alone in PHP.

This means you can comfortably use it in CodeIgniter.

https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade

Then again, you will need `composer` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use this CodeIgniter Library to simulate Blade: [CodeIgniter Slice-Libray](https://github.com/GustMartins/Slice-Library)

It works pretty like Blade and it was designed directly for CodeIgniter!

Answer (score 1):

For the record and as answer to another post:

I tested many libraries to run blade outside Laravel (that i don't use) and most (with all respect of the coders) are poor hacks of the original library that simply copied and pasted the code and removed some dependencies yet **it retains a lot of dependencies of Laravel**.

I created an alternative  for blade that its free (MIT license, i.e. close source/private code is OK) in a **single file and without a single dependency of an external library**.  You could download the class and start using it, or you could install via composes (composer require eftec/bladeone). So even composer is optional.

https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne

https://packagist.org/packages/eftec/bladeone

Its 100% compatible sans the Laravel's own features (extensions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BladeView](https://github.com/aididalam/Codeigniter-Blade-Template) library for CI.
*NB: I ported this library*

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("bladeview");
  }

 public function renderView(){
    $data=array(
            "name"=>"Jhon",
            "age"=>21
        );
    $this->bladeview->render("test", $data);
 }

 public function renderString(){
    $data=array(
            "name"=>"Jhon",
            "age"=>21
        );
    $string="Hello I'm \{{$name}}. My age is \{{$age}}";
    $this->bladeview->render($string, $data,false);
  }
}
```

then in view.blade.php you can render like you do in laravel blade.

```
Hello my name is {{$name}}. My Age is {{$age}}.
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is Jhon. My Age is 21.
```

Comment: Please note that, if you provide a link to a website or blog to which you are affiliated (such as the GitHub you suggest), then you must **explicitly** disclose that affiliation; otherwise, the community may consider your post **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: Thank you. I didn' know that..

Answer (score 0):

I have done a full write up here: http://mstd.eu/index.php/2017/03/02/using-the-laravel-blade-templating-engine-in-codeigniter-3/

Basically, include the package with composer (you need to set CI up to use composer), then create a blade instance passing it your view and cache folder like so:

```
$blade = new BladeInstance(__DIR__ . "/../views", __DIR__ . "/../cache/views");

echo $blade->render("index");
```

Comment: The link is down... is it still availeble somewhere?

Comment: @Gonzalingui https://web.archive.org/web/20170827182241/http://mstd.eu/index.php/2017/03/02/using-the-laravel-blade-templating-engine-in-codeigniter-3/